# how to get parent folder name in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

`file:/C:/workspace/Spark_Scala_Exercise2/src/main/Resources/exercise-2/input/run_1/batch_id=73/part-00000-7489f493-c825-469a-9877-0b0e2c75cd4b.c000.snappy.parquet` like i have many files

from this 
i only want batch_id column with 73

Comment: this is more of Scala question rather than Spark

Comment: why is this scala problem? I believe, this is spark problem, please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

One way is to split the string by "/", after that delete the last part (".....parquet") and then kepp only the last element

```
def getParent(path: String) : String = {
    //split the string into an array
    val tmpList = path
      .split("/")
    //remove the last element and after that keep only the last one.
    val parent = tmpList.dropRight(1).last

    parent
}
```

To apply that function on a column you can use

```
val getParentPath = udf((path: String) => {
     //split the string into an array
        val tmpList = path
          .split("/")
        //remove the last element and after that keep only the last one.
        val parent = tmpList.dropRight(1).last

        parent
})
val dfWithPath = oldDf.withColumn("parent_path", getParentPath($"path")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can be done in 2 steps as below

```
import java.nio.file.{Path, Paths}

object GetParentFolderName {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    //Create Path from the input string
    val path : Path = Paths.get("file:/C:/workspace/Spark_Scala_Exercise2/src/main/Resources/exercise-2/input/run_1/batch_id=73/part-00000-7489f493-c825-469a-9877-0b0e2c75cd4b.c000.snappy.parquet")

    //Get Parent folder name
    println(path.getParent.getFileName)
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are trying to read a saved files with a partition `batch_id`
Try this-

### create the files partitioned by `batch_id`

> This is how it looks in my case `/Users/sokale/models/run_1/batch_id=73/part-00001-5fa5aebb-a836-43d2-97d2-7cf9bb722c26.c000.snappy.parquet`

```scala
  val df = spark.range(1,5)
      .withColumn("batch_id", lit(70) + col("id"))

    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+--------+
      * |id |batch_id|
      * +---+--------+
      * |1  |71      |
      * |2  |72      |
      * |3  |73      |
      * |4  |74      |
      * +---+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: long (nullable = false)
      * |-- batch_id: long (nullable = false)
      */

    df.write.partitionBy("batch_id")
      .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
      .parquet("/Users/sokale/models/run_1")
    /**
      * $ cd run_1/
      * $ ls -l
      * total 0
      * ............ _SUCCESS
      * ............ batch_id=71
      * ............ batch_id=72
      * ............ batch_id=73
      * ............ batch_id=74
      */
```

### 2. Read the parquet file for partition `barch_id=73`

From the [spark doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/sql-programming-guide.html#configuration)-

```
spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown    default-true    Enables Parquet filter push-down optimization when set to true.
```

that means `df.read.parquet(dir).where(partitionCOndition)` only read the the specified partitioned directory using filter push down

```scala
 // read only file with batch_id=73
    spark.read.parquet("/Users/sokale/models/run_1").where(col("batch_id").equalTo(73))
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +---+--------+
      * |id |batch_id|
      * +---+--------+
      * |3  |73      |
      * +---+--------+
      */
    // read all partitions
    val readDF = spark.read.parquet("/Users/sokale/models/run_1")
    readDF.show(false)
    readDF.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+--------+
      * |id |batch_id|
      * +---+--------+
      * |3  |73      |
      * |2  |72      |
      * |1  |71      |
      * |4  |74      |
      * +---+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: long (nullable = true)
      * |-- batch_id: integer (nullable = true)
      */
```

Comment: u got it right but my problem is i have already huge data. like run_1 der is run_2,3,4 within that manyparttion folder. and i created column withcoulm name batch_id and input_file_name() it's take full path i want only batch id no in batch_id column.

Comment: while reading the path give only `/C:/workspace/Spark_Scala_Exercise2/src/main/Resources/exercise-2/input/run_1` and apply where clause on `batch_id` since spark has predicate push down- see spark doc- https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.2/sql-programming-guide.html#configuration. I don't think you need to create column for partition. please check my answer again. If you have other requirement please let me know

Comment: @user9141806, Feel fee to accept + upvote if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this for all the run_1, run_2, run_3, etc at once:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet("file:/C:/workspace/Spark_Scala_Exercise2/src/main/Resources/exercise-2/input/*/*")
df.select("batch_id").distinct.show
```

Comment: batch_id not a column here .